# .Net web service is unable to process complex object in JSON

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest, serialization

Here you ca find my web service content :

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IProcessing
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "person/{id}")]
    Person GetPerson(string id);
}
```

I have two model, Person and Picture.
When I try to get picture from my web serivce in JSON, everything is good and the result returned by WS is correct.

**But this is not the same when i trying to send Person Object.beacuse Person contains Picture.**

Here you can find my models properties:

```
 Person : 
{
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    /// <summary>
    /// Class which define the object Person.
    /// </summary>
    [DataContract]
    public class Person
    {
        #region Constructor

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        public Person()
        {

        }
```

Picture :

```
/// <summary>
    /// Class which define the object Team.
    /// </summary>
    [DataContract]
    public class Picture
    {
        #region Constructor

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        public Picture()
        {

        }

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the id of the picture
        /// </summary>
        [DataMember]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the url of the picture
        /// </summary>
        [DataMember]
        public string URL { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the color code of the picture
        /// </summary>
        [DataMember]
        public string ColorCode { get; set; }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

Comment: how you serialize/deserialize your objects? do you get any error/exception?

Comment: I just serialize my objects, and as I don't have any result when testing ws on browser ! I didn't try to deserialize it yet!

Comment: Do you get errors or exceptions?

Comment: can you give us the exact exception you're getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have set Known Type attribute in the Person header? 
here is good example for complex objects
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I add it right know, but nothing is changed !
It's really curious : can't send Obejct that conatins another one on JSON !!

Comment: Person was the parent class of two other classes , in Person i just added the two other classes KnownType and not only once who contain it and it works great.